# How to render a maximum of ten items in the react.js object

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react I want to render a maximum of ten items on the screen if I have more than 10 items in an array of objects.

This is what I have so far it does render a maximum of ten items but i have hard coded it, I want it do it automatically when my array have more than 10 items in an array.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      musicians: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "artist 1",
          display: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Artist 2",
          display: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Artist 3",
          display: false
       };
    ]
    this.numRows = 0;
  };
  render() {
    const artistToRender = this.state.musicians.filter(artist => artist.display);
    const numRows = artistToRender.length;

return (
  <div>
    <p>Number of rows = {numRows}</p>
    {artistToRender.map((artist) => {
        return <li>{ artist.name }</li>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see [**Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kugva1) the complete answer, it's work

```js
<ul>
    {
      artistToRender.map((el,i)=> {
         return (<li key={el.id}>{el.name}</li>)
    }).filter((e,k) => k < 10)
    }
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list to the first 10 items first:

```
    {artistToRender.filter((_,idx) => (idx<10))
                   .map((artist) => {
        return <li>{ artist.name }</li>
    })}
```